# "Backwards" Conditionals in C

Tags: c, conditional-statements

I'm looking through some code and I found some strange conditionals, namely:

```
if (NULL != buf) {...}
```

I was wondering if there was a particular reason for writing the conditional like this, instead of

```
if(buf != NULL){...}
```

I can't see any reason to do it the first way off the top of my head, but I don't think it was a mistake. To me, it seems like they accomplish the same thing, but the second way is way more intuitive. Is there some specific reason to use the first conditional?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yoda_conditions

Comment: Also, 'if(0==somecallThatReturns0OnSuccess(loads, of ,lengthy, parameters)){DoStuff};'   can look cleaner and be easier to trace through when debugging.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, it's called "[Yoda conditions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yoda_conditions)".  The idea is to not accidentally assign a value when you mean to be doing a check.  Most modern compilers should catch it.

Answer (score 4):

It is to avoid newbie typo like `if (buf = NULL)`.

`if (NULL = buf)` leads to compilation error, while `if (buf = NULL)` is totally correct with undesired semantic.

Comment: With compiler warning enabled `if (buf = NULL)` would trigger a _Using the result of an assignment as a truth value is recommended with explicit parentheses_ or something like that.

Answer (score 3):

The concept is basically this:

Often new learners miss the double equals sign `==` and use a single `=` instead. Instructors therefore teach them this method so that they are not stuck at simple programs.

With no compiler warnings enabled, if you do this:

```
if(buf = NULL)
```

You are basically assigning NULL to `buf`, which is not syntactically wrong, and you would not get any warnings, but when you do this:

```
if(NULL = buf)
```

the compiler throws error because it knows you cannot assign anything to NULL.

> Why Yoda in particular?

It's because of the character Yoda, from Star Wars, whose dialogues were styled in reverse orders, like " Blue is the sky".

You can read more interesting coding terms [here](http://www.dodgycoder.net/2011/11/yoda-conditions-pokemon-exception.html?spref=bl).

Answer (score 2):

This will give a compiler error if comparison expression is mis typed as assignment expression.

For example, if you compile

```
if (buf = NULL) {}
```

the compiler says,

> warning: suggest parentheses around assignment used as truth value [-Wparentheses]

but if you change it to

```
if (NULL = buf) {}
```

the compiler now says,

> error: lvalue required as left operand of assignment